# No threads left running after using ThreadPoolExecutor in Java

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

Pool size=8, active threads=0, queued tasks=0, completed tasks=5678. Why active threads are 0 when thread pool is active. Could some one explain me this. It suppose to be more than 0 right?

Comment: since there is no code, i just could guess that you read the attributes after the execution is done, so no threads are occupied by the executor anymore

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

I suspect you set your core pool size to zero, or you said to let core threads time-out.

## `allowCoreThreadTimeOut( true )`

To quote from the *Keep-alive times* section of the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) Javadoc:

> By default, the keep-alive policy applies only when there are more than corePoolSize threads, but method [`allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)) can be used to apply this time-out policy to core threads as well, so long as the keepAliveTime value is non-zero.

Pass true or false to that method to:

> [set] the policy governing whether core threads may time out and terminate if no tasks arrive within the keep-alive time, being replaced if needed when new tasks arrive.

## `setCorePoolSize( 0 )`

If you set the core pool size to zero, all threads will eventually time-out. In this case, setting `allowCoreTheadTimeOut` is irrelevant.

See the *Reclamation* section of that Javadoc page:

> You can configure a pool to allow all unused threads to eventually die by setting appropriate keep-alive times, using a lower bound of zero core threads and/or setting allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean).

Comment: Thank you. This threadpool was created by Spring framework, I havent. I am sure the corepool size isnot zero. This thread pool is for outbound channel to send data to clients in webscokets. I see the data is being sent to client as a continuous stream, but the active count is zero from threadpool. So, as you said, there is a option to die the idle threads of core pool size and do you think thats the reason i am able to see active threads as 0?

Comment: @Pavani For a more specific answer, you will need to post more specific code, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).